# How to make an SVG element transparent (using SVGweb)

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, transparency, transparent, fill

In a SVG document, I want to make a `<path>`-element transparent. I tried `<path fill="transparent />"` but this gives me a black surface in ie8 (which is the default color for unknown values).  I use SVGweb to display the SVG in ie8. How do I make it appear transparent in ie8?

EDIT:

According to the SVG-SPEC ( http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#SpecifyingPaint ), the attribute `fill` takes a value of type `<paint>`. the value `currentColor` does work in ie8, yet it's not supported by ff and chrome.

So I'd like to reshape my question:
How do I make it appear transparent in ff, chrome and ie8 simultaneously?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
fill="none"
```

Or you can cheat (and hurt performance) with:

```
fill-opacity="0"
```

Comment: well, `fill="transparent"` is not the same as `fill="none"` (first is :hover-able). `fill-opacity="0"` is working for me.

Comment: both are "hoverable" as long as you use the right value for 'pointer-events', see http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty.