# SVG path with transparent fill becomes grey with TCPDF

Tags: svg, tcpdf

I have a number of SVG images being inserted into a PDF file using TCPDF. For example:

```
<path d="M0 100 L 80 100 L 40 27 L 0 100" stroke="black" fill="transparent" stroke-width="5" />
```

The problem is that TCPDF seems to turn any transparency to grey. How can I make it transparent? I cannot simply turn it to white as it is being placed on top of other data as well.

Many of the shapes are complex, utilizing bezier curves and stroke arrays so I need to use a path rather than lines, polygons, or polylines.

Comment: fill="transparent" is not part of the SVG specification, it comes from html so something that only supports SVG might not implement it.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the info!

Answer (score 1):

I think this might not be possible, but I have found a workaround. Rather than setting

```
fill="transparent"
```

I just use:

```
fill="none"
```

or

```
fill-opacity="0"
```

This seems to work fine. Both can be found on this page:

[How to make an SVG element transparent (using SVGweb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054701/how-to-make-an-svg-element-transparent-using-svgweb)